# How to see this form for the chemical potential of an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

In Chapter 13.2 of his text, Callen states that the chemical potential with respect to the $j$th component of an ideal gas can be written as
$$\mu_j = RT \left[\phi_j(T) + \ln P + \ln x_j \right].$$
where $\phi_j$ is some function of temperature $T$, $P$ is the pressure of the overall system, and $x_j \equiv N_j/N$ is the mole fraction of component $j$.

He states this outright and doesn't prove it, and I am trying to do so now. Based on what has been developed in the text thus far, I am trying to do it by using the free energy.

We have
$$\mu_j \equiv \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial N_j} \right)_{T,V,N_i; \, i \neq j} \stackrel{(1)}{=} \left( \frac{\partial F_j}{\partial  N_j} \right)_{T,V,N_i; \, i \neq j} = \left( \frac{\partial U_j}{\partial  N_j} \right)_{T,V,N_i; \, i \neq j} + T\left( \frac{\partial S_j}{\partial  N_j} \right)_{T,V,N_i; \, i \neq j}.$$
where (1) follows from the additivity of the free energy/Helmholtz potential for an ideal gas. Thus it remains to evaluate the unknown derivatives.

I try to do this below but get lost. Callen shows that
$$U_j = N_ju_{j0} + N_j\int_{T_0}^T c_{vj} \, dT'$$
and
$$S_j = N_js_{j0} + N_j\int_{T_0}^T \frac{c_{vj}}{T'} \, dT' + N_j R \ln \left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right)$$.
Thus, differentiating even just the first one I get:
$$\left( \frac{\partial U_j}{\partial  N_j} \right)_{T,V,N_i; \, i \neq j} = u_{j0} +\int_{T_0}^T c_{vj} \, dT' +N_j\int_{T_0}^T \left( \frac{\partial c_{vj}}{\partial  N_j} \right)_{T',V,N_i; \, i \neq j}\,dT'$$
$$ = u_{j0} +\int_{T_0}^T c_{vj} \, dT' +N_j\int_{T_0}^T \left( \frac{\partial \left(\frac{T'}{N}\left( \frac{\partial S_j}{\partial  T'} \right)_{V,N_j}  \right)}{\partial  N_j} \right)_{T',V,N_i; \, i \neq j} \,dT'$$
$$= u_{j0} +\int_{T_0}^T c_{vj} \, dT' - \frac{N_j}{N^2}\int_{T_0}^T T' \left(\frac{\left( \frac{\partial S_j}{\partial  T} \right)_{V,N_j}}{\partial  N_j} \right)_{T,V,N_i; \, i \neq j}$$
but I can't go any further, and surely the derivative of the entropy will get even uglier. Can anyone provide some help as to how to proceed?

Comment: Please, provide the definitions for the parameters in $$\mu_j = RT \left[\phi_j(T) + \ln P + \ln x_j \right].$$

Comment: Edited to reflect that. @Sgg8